# How to save multiselect box value to magento cms table?

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes, cms

I have added multiselect box attribute to cms page with following code

```
$fieldset->addField('counts', 'multiselect', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Total Counts'),
        'name'      => 'counts',
        'values'    => array(

            array(
                'value'     => 0,
                'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('One'),
            ),
            array(
                'value'     => 1,
                'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Two'),
            ),

            array(
                'value'     => 2,
                'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Three'),
            ),  
            array(
                'value'     => 3,
                'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('FOur'),
            ),                                        
        ),
        'value' => $model->getCounts(),
    ));
```

When i save, its saved as "Array".Please anyone help me to save the option values to the database..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, you need to transform your array to a string before saving it to the database.

This can be done in an observer listening to `cms_page_load_after/before` to transform string to array and `cms_page_save_before/after` to transform it back. And after the saving it should be transformed back...

How to use event/observer: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method in the observer you get the `$page = $observer->getPage()` and then you set `$page->setYourAttribute(implode(',', $page->getYourAttribute());`

Comment: I just added foreach ($data as $key => $value)
   {
    if (is_array($value))
    {
     $data[$key] = implode(',',$this->getRequest()->getParam($key)); 
    }
   }   
after $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost() in saveAction(). Now its working fine.

Comment: there are a lot of reasons why this is a bad idea, if this is  a core hack. Just google "magento core hack"

Comment: But i have done this through extending Mage_Adminhtml_Cms_PageController.

Comment: Then it is ok :-)